# Generate dates starts with last day of a month and ends with first day of a month

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have dates always with 1st day of the month like: `2022-11-01` and `2022-01-01`. I want to get dates with last days of the month (so it will be `2022-11-30` and `2022-10-31`) etc and then subtract 3 months from these dates.

So for date `2022-11-01` I want to see array with dates from `2022-09-01` to `2022-11-30` and from
`2021-10-01` to `2022-01-31`:

I expect table like this:

| new_date |
| --- |
| 2022-11-30 |
| 2022-11-29 |
| 2022-11-28 |
| ... |
| 2022-09-03 |
| 2022-09-02 |
| 2022-09-01 |

I tried with:

```
WITH subtractDays(addMonths(toDate('2022-11-01'), 1),1) as start
SELECT subtractDays(toDate(start), number) AS new_date
FROM (
    SELECT arrayJoin(range(0, 90)) AS number)
```

But I get `2022-09-02` at the end. It happens because inside arrayJoin I use 90 days, so this thing doesnt understand that month can have 31, 30, 29 days..
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```sql
SELECT arrayJoin(data_range) AS new_date
FROM 
(
    WITH toDate('2022-11-01') AS dt
    SELECT
        dt,
        addMonths(dt, -2) AS from,
        addMonths(dt, 1) AS to,
        arrayMap(x -> (from + x), range(toUInt32(to - from))) AS data_range
)

/*
┌───new_date─┐
│ 2022-09-01 │
│ 2022-09-02 │
...
│ 2022-11-29 │
│ 2022-11-30 │
└────────────┘
*/
```